# How to print variables inside a PHP Event?

Tags: craft3, php, plugin-sproutforms

I'm trying to work with the Sprout Forms events to grab a variable from the form and add it to a filename also uploaded through the same form.  I am extremely stuck and so far I can't even confirm that the event itself is working.  What I need to do is grab the variables from the form on the event after save.  To start, how do I print the variables in the event?  Do I need to do a second function?

```
Event::on(Entry::class, Entry::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE, function(Event $event) {
        $formEntry = $event->sender;
        $fieldHandle = $formEntry->getRequiredParam('fieldHandle');
        print $fieldHandle;
    });
```

Also, dumb question, do events need to be inside of a Controller?

Comment: You want to print it out to see if your event is being hit? You can use `die($fieldHandle);` and that'll halt the rest of the request while outputting the value. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.die.php

Comment: Make sure the 'Entry' variable in your code refers to the Sprout Forms Entry Element and not the Craft Entry Element. Sometimes an editor can autocomplete the wrong reference there: `use barrelstrength\sproutforms\elements\Entry`. And, as die works like Brad described, if you need a look at the whole event, Craft provides a statement that can output the whole event object `\Craft::dd($event);`